# Ubuntu can't be booted from DVD drive?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, windows-8.1

I bought a Lenovo Ideapad G50-70 (with pre-installed Windows 8.1) lately. Thinking of dual-boot, I downloaded the Ubuntu LiveCD, and created a bootable disc. Later, I restarted the PC (with my CD inserted) and got into the boot menu.

The problem is that my boot menu doesn't show the DVD drive. It just shows the Windows bootloader. But, I'm quite sure that the DVD drive runs when I turn my PC on (because, it freezes for a second at the splash screen).

I checked whether the CD is bootable with a friend's laptop. It was fine, it did load the LiveCD. I can't guess what the problem could be. Any helpful suggestion would be appreciated.

**Update:** I tried a few workarounds (like [this one](http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) and [this one](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?271-How-to-EFI-install-Kali-Linux)), but they don't seem to help me in any way. For USB, it said "Booting from USB failed!" and for the CD drive, it said the same - "Booting from CD/DVD ROM failed!"

**Update 2:** Looks like I totally forgot to switch UEFI boot to Legacy Support. When I did that, linux GRUB came in like a sauce. I was able to boot directly from my USB & DVD.

Comment: probably need to go to BIOS and disable `Secure Boot` and , of course, have DVD as a first boot device enabled.

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov: I did try that. But, my boot menu doesn't have an option for DVD/USB. It's got only the default Windows bootloader :/

Comment: You said that finally you started having message "Booting from CD/DVD ROM failed!" that made me think you had chosen Boot from DVD or USB previously. By the way, what program did you use to make Live USB? Also, did you check `md5sum`s after downloading ISO and after you put it on USB/DVD with the original hash?

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov: (Oops...) When I accessed the boot menu directly, I had the only one choice (default bootloader). Later, I tried using the UEFI startup options to boot from USB/DVD, when that error popped up during boot. So far, I've used Win32 Disk Imager, Universal USB Installer and PowerISO. Regarding the `md5sum`, do I really need to do that? Because, it did work fine on my friend's laptop. (Googling around, I found that UEFIs don't accept 32-bit versions, mine's a 32-bit version. Could that be a problem?)

Comment: You may want to give `win32 disk-imager` a try. I usually make it like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XoINdNWVgYo

Answer (score 0):

There are interesting points written [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392719/32-bit-uefi-boot-support) on close thread by Rod Smith,
quoting:

Broadly speaking, if you need to install Ubuntu (or any other Linux distribution) on a computer with a 32-bit EFI and no BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode boot support, the way to do it is:

1. Use [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) or something similar to prepare an installation USB flash drive. (It's possible to get it to work with a CD-R, but this takes more work.)
2. Choose an [EFI-mode boot loader for Linux.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) I recommend ELILO, Fedora's patched GRUB Legacy, rEFInd, or gummiboot because they're relatively easy to set up manually. GRUB 2 is far too difficult to configure manually, and SYSLINUX is too new.
3. Research your chosen boot loader's configuration file format and its needs in terms of kernel location.
4. Check the original CD image to find its boot loader configuration. You need to know what options are being passed to the kernel by the boot loader.
5. Add an `EFI/BOOT` directory to a FAT partition on the USB flash drive that now holds your Linux image. Ideally, this partition should be an ESP (that is, have a "boot flag" set in `parted` or have a type code of EF00 in `gdisk` if the disk uses GPT; or have a type code of 0xEF in `fdisk` if the disk uses MBR), but some ESPs can cope without that. If the disk doesn't have a FAT partition, you'll need to create one
6. Copy your chosen boot loader's binary file (with a name that ends in `.efi`) to the `EFI/BOOT` directory on the USB flash drive, and rename it to `bootia32.efi` -- that is, it should be `EFI/BOOT/bootia32.efi`. Be sure to copy the *32-bit* version of the boot loader!
7. Install any support files that the boot loader needs, such as drivers, images, modules, and configuration files. In some cases (such as ELILO and gummiboot), you'll need to copy your kernel and initrd file to the FAT partition that holds the boot loader.
8. Edit the configuration file(s) for your boot loader so that it can launch the kernel with the options you identified earlier by examining the BIOS-mode boot loader's configuration.
9. Reboot to test the boot loader.

With any luck it will work and you'll be able  to install everything. I can't guarantee that Ubuntu will install a 32-bit EFI boot loader, though. If not, you'll need to boot an emergency system and set that up manually, too. You may also need to debug something, particularly if unetbootin (or whatever you use) doesn't set up the flash drive in the optimal way.

Of course, this description is fairly vague about the critical detail of configuring the boot loader. This is because I haven't done it recently (although I have in the past), and the details vary depending on what boot loader you choose.